# It's possible to communicate with google assistant using asp.net without dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

My intention is make custom layer between Google Assistant and Dilogflow, possibly using asp.net but not necessarily. It's possible?

I read all google assistant sdk documentation but I not foud nothing of useful.

I expect to be able to send message from my application to Google Assistant action and the other way around.

Comment: You should be more specific about what you mean by "custom layer between Google Assistant and Dialogflow"

Comment: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-dotnet-client